# Working at same place 2 years & my colleagues got a salary increase but I didn't. Should I ask my boss why?

Tags: salary, career, salary-increase, raise

I have worked at a doctors practice for two years. Some of my collegues have made a year working in this practice, but they have increased their salary. I didn't get an increase when they did.

What might be the cause of this? Should I ask my boss why or should I keep quiet?

Comment: You might also be interested in this question: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-much-would-be-a-fair-raise-or-salary-increase-to-ask-for-at-work

Answer (score 16):

If you are unhappy with your salary you should definitely discuss it with your boss.

However, I would suggest not bringing up what other people in the company are making or what raises they might have recently received. That is irrelevant, it isn't a competition or a parent handing out allowances to all of their children. Your salary is the negotiated amount based on your value to the company and what you reasonably can get in the marketplace.

So when you ask for a raise you are re-entering that negotiation and need to have something new to bring to the table. That is, why are you worth more now than when you previously agreed to work for your current salary? Your best bet is to demonstrate that you have gained new experience/skills that are valuable to the employer or that you have taken on greater responsibility.

One other thing. I'd avoid the line of argument that raises are necessary to keep up with inflation. While this is often true (not so much this year), you really need to frame the discussion in terms of the extra value you are providing, not in terms of your own financial situation.

**Update based on comments:**
The only inflation that matters in this discussion is that for labor prices for your specific job. Those tend to jump up AND DOWN quite a bit over the years. If you want to make the inflation argument you should be willing to take a pay cut whenever the job market starts tanking. The price of eggs and gas are immaterial from the perspective of your employment contract.

Comment: +1 Good advice, I wish more people in our society thought about things this way.

Comment: +1 I liked the competition and child allowances analogy.

Comment: I disagree about not bringing up inflation. If you are not getting a pay raise equal to inflation, then your real wages are going down. You don't have to be bringing something extra to the table to be paid the same in real terms. In these recessionary times "everybody's suffering" is usually the reason.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I'm not arguing that inflation doesn't deflate the value of your salary. If you read closely, I am saying that you should never argue for a raise in terms of what's in it for you. To make a compelling argument you need to frame it in terms of what THEY are getting, not what  YOU are getting. It isn't about fairness. It is about strategy. Would you rather be right or get the raise?

Comment: The part is was disagreeing with was when you wrote "you need to have something new to bring to the table". I would use the argument "I'm working just as well as a year ago, why am I being paid less?"

Comment: If you say so. I'm just telling you from the perspective of someone who has heard that argument and been in a position to decide raises that it isn't very persuasive.

Comment: @JohnFx What is your actual answer when someone asks "I'm doing the same work as last year, why are you paying me less in real terms?"

Comment: @DJClayworth - What would be your response if your garbage pickup service said the same thing? Probably the same as mine: "I'm paying what we negotiated. If you need more, ask for it." Maybe I'll pay it, maybe I won't. However, you'd probably feel a lot better about paying more if they prefaced the discussion with the value you were getting rather than how they are jacking up the price because you are screwing them somehow through doing nothing but sticking to the terms of the agreement.

Comment: You should always use all of your arguments, including inflation. Looking for a raise when inflation is rising is on your interest -- reducing your salary in other circumstances is the other parties problem. I'd rather be a hippocrite than a guy with consistent arguments who cannot afford to go on vacation.

Comment: @JohnFx OK, good point. I'd be unhappy with a company that didn't give me a pay raise in line with inflation, unless I was either performing worse than last year or the company was in deep trouble. And by 'unhappy' I mean updating my resume.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I think you may be missing my key message. That message is: If you are unhappy with your compensation, talk to your manager. Don't just sit around and get mad. However, if you haven't been getting even Cost of living raises, be prepared for the possibility that it isn't that they are just being cheap, especially if others are getting them. I don't condone this, but many passive aggressive managers use this as a technique to get low-performers to self-select themselves out of the organization without having to fire them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't focus on the salary directly -- I would have a discussion with your boss about *your performance* and strategies to improve. Keep your mind open and don't get upset if you don't hear whatever you expected.